# How can we instantiate the constructor in Akka Actor?

Tags: java, mocking, akka, testng

I am writing unit tests for my akka actor classes. a field is being declared in abstract parent class and instantiated inside its constructor. During test case execution of child class that field is showing null. So how to instantiate the field from the test class. 
Note: I am using partial Mocking also in testNG classes.

```
public abstract class ParentClass extends UntypedActor {
    protected RestTemplate restTemplate;
    protected ObjectMapper objMapper;

    public ParentClass () {
        super();
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        objMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    }
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    public ChildClass () {
        super();
    }
    public void invoke(String json) throws Exception {
      BeanClass bean = objMapper.readValue(json, Bean.class);
       }

    public String getJsonResponse(String json){
     sysout("Get");
     return "response";
       }
}

public class ChildClassUnitTest {
@BeforeTest
    public  void  setUp() throws Exception{

    actorMock = PowerMock.createPartialMock(ChildClass.class,"getJsonResponse");

        actorMock.getJsonResponse("req");
        PowerMock.expectLastCall().andReturn("resp").anyTimes();
        PowerMock.replay(actorMock);

    } 

    @Test
    public void testInvokePos() throws Exception{

        ResponseClass response=actorMock.invoke("req");
        System.out.println(response);

    }
}
```

Comment: would you like to share code here  ?

Comment: Hi SacJn I have uploaded dummy code. Please take a look.

Comment: have you read the Akka docs on testing actors? you can only create an instance of an actor via Props and therefore you use TestActorRef in a test scenario. You can then get access to the underlyingActor. I'm not sure mocking will work as you are hoping in your example http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not known to json and I can only help with java code. 
Please look at code below. 
And my instance fields are initialized properly. They are not null. So I don't see any problem with your code atleast with what you have posted. Need to visit your `UntypedActor` class.

```
class ClassA
{
    String x;
    public ClassA ()
    {
        x = "Java";

    }
}

abstract class ParentClass extends ClassA{
    protected String restTemplate;
    protected Integer objMapper;

    public ParentClass () {
        super();
        restTemplate = " Language";
        objMapper = 1;

    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    public ChildClass () {
        super();
    }

}

class HelloWorld 
{
    public static void main (String args[] )
    {

        ChildClass cc = new ChildClass ();
        System.out.println ( cc.x + cc.restTemplate + cc.objMapper );
    }
}
```

Output for the code is as expected

> Java Language1